Title: Unable to Retrieve Instagram Followers Count for Some Facebook Accounts
am working with the Instagram Graph API to retrieve Instagram followers count for accounts linked to Facebook Pages. I am using the following scopes: instagram_basic and pages_show_list.
While the API works for some Facebook accounts and returns the Instagram followers count correctly, it does not work for other accounts, even though those accounts have Instagram Business or Creator accounts linked to their Facebook Pages.
Here’s an outline of my setup:
I use the endpoint GET /{page_id}?fields=instagram_business_account to fetch the Instagram Business Account ID.
Once I have the Instagram Business Account ID, I query GET /{instagram_account_id}?fields=followers_count to get the followers count.
For some Facebook Pages, the instagram_business_account field is returned as null, even though the Instagram accounts are properly linked to the Facebook Pages.
I have ensured:
The access token has the required permissions (instagram_basic, pages_show_list).
The user token is generated correctly, and the app is authorized for all required permissions.
The Instagram accounts in question are Business or Creator accounts and linked correctly to the Facebook Pages.
Has anyone faced a similar issue? Are there additional permissions or configurations needed to consistently fetch the Instagram Business Account ID and followers count?
Any guidance or insights would be appreciated!
Thank you.
